# Why do I need a .swc file when compiling against an Adobe Native Extension?

Tags: air, adobe, flash, air-native-extension, swc

I'm new to Adobe AIR development and have been developing a Native Extension.

Apparently, I need to include with the `.ane` file, a `.swc` file that is needed to build against the `.ane`. Why is this? Why can't the developer just build against the `.ane`? What is missing in the `.ane` that the `.swc` provides?

I'm trying to write internal documentation about the project and have gotten stuck on this question.

Answer (score 1):

The SWC is totally unnecessary in most development situations.

There are two situations where the SWC may be required:

- If you are using an older development environment, where ANE's weren't supported you may be required to use a SWC to successfully build your code and then package with adt from the command line
- If you are trying to use an ANE in a library, you'll need to build the library against the SWC and then package your application with the library and the ANE

A decent ANE developer will actually include a SWC packaged inside the ANE. The default library should be included in every ANE to handle the situations where the platform isn't supported (returning isSupported false etc). So when distributing ANE's you don't need to include a SWC, as it can be obtained via the following:

- unzip the ANE
- browse to `META-INF/ANE/default`
- use the SWC located in that directory

Answer (score 0):

You do not necessarily have to use an SWC in combination with an ANE. The ANE does already work standalone. I have used a few ANEs (like Native Dialog, Vibration, AdMob) without the SWC. However, I cannot answer why most of the time an SWC exists.

Answer (score 0):

When you developing your ANE - you must provide AS3 API wrapping classes that your AS3 editor will read and use it for code hints + compiler will know what to do when you compile your app.

ANE contain swc inside so you don't neet to provide eexternal swc. Just use 1 ANE. Buy SWC is required to ANE developing. Not for end user. But I know in some cases old software don't know how to parse ane correctly and you need to provide also swc.

But I don't use swc + ane. Just one ANE.